# "Any salary or compensation or experience certificate" vs. "any salary certificate or compensation certificate or experience certificate"

Tags: word-choice, parallelism, modifiers

How should I write this?

> - ... shall not be eligible for any salary or compensation or experience certificate if the Trainee fails to co-operate with XYZ for the exit formalities
> - ... shall not be eligible for any salary certificate or compensation certificate or experience certificate if the Trainee fails to co-operate with XYZ for the exit formalities

What I want the reader to understand from this sentence is that they wouldn't be entitled to any certificates (for salary/compensation/experience) if they don't co-operate with XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would say:

> ....shall not be eligible for any certificate (e.g. of salary,
> compensation or experience) if the Trainee fails to co-operate with
> XYZ for the exit formalities.